# How to set scroll position of WebPage Containing Iframe at top when that page is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

We have a ASPX page containing an iframe. Iframe used to store content of page.
Our problem is suppose we have an data (Editable Rows) on one page with scrollbar. If we click on upper part of page row then The new page open correctly i.e. it is open & scrollbar position at top.
But when we click lower part Row then The page which we open have scroll position at bottom.
How can we make that scroll position to top?
Till now we have tried ,

```
window.onload = function () {
$('html').scrollTop(0);
```

&

```
 var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("Content");
            myIframe.onload = function () {
                myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
            };
```

&

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

But no luck. please help.

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var Ifr = parent.document.getElementById("Content");

            Ifr.onload = function () {

                parent.scrollTo(0, 0);
            };

});
```